# Call to undefined method App\User::role() in Laravel

Tags: laravel, roles

I want to create a list of users with their specific role(or roles if multiple roles given)

In my UserController

```
use DB;
use Auth;
use Storage;

use App\Role;
use App\HasRoles;
use App\User;
use App\Profile;

$users = User::with('roles')->where('name', 'admin')->get();
return view('dashboard.users.index', compact('users'));
```

but I am having this error

[image]

if I `dd($users);`

I can see that the roles are there

[image]

How can I solve the issue? thanks!

EDIT: user model

```
use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\MustVerifyEmail;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;

class User extends Authenticatable implements MustVerifyEmail
{
    use Notifiable, HasRoles;

    protected $fillable = [
        'name', 'email', 'phone_number', 'avatar', 'password', 'verification_code'
    ];

    protected $hidden = [
        'password', 'remember_token',
    ];

    protected $casts = [
        'email_verified_at' => 'datetime',
        'phone_verified_at' => 'datetime',
    ];

    public function profile()
    {
        return $this->hasOne('App\Profile', 'user_id','id');
    }

    public function mailingAdd()
    {
        return $this->hasOne('App\MailingAddress', 'user_id','id');
    }
```

user/index.php

```
@foreach($users->role as $item)
    <tr>
        <td>{{ $loop->iteration }}</td>
        <td><a href="{{ url('/dashboard/users', $item->id) }}">{{ $item->name }}</a></td>
        <td>{{ $item->email }}</td>
        <td>{{ $item->role()->name }}</td>
        <td>{{ $item->phone_number==null ? 'None' : $item->phone_number  }}</td>
        <td>
            @if($item->phone_verfied_at==null)
                <span class="badge badge-danger">not yet verified</span>
            @else
                <span class="badge badge-success">verified</span>
            @endif
        </td>
    </tr>
@endforeach
```

Changing `@foreach($users->role as $item)` into `@foreach($user->roles as $item)` gives me "Property [roles] does not exist on this collection instance"

USER TABLE MIGRATION

[image]

ROLES AND PERMISSION TABLE MIGRATION

[image]

**ANSWER**

base from **Simon Morris**'s answer.

```
@foreach($users as $user)
    {{ $user->name }}
    @foreach ($user->roles as $role)
        {{ $role->name }}
    @endforeach
@endforeach
```

I removed the relationship I added base from some of my suggestions here. and implement the answer I pasted above.

That code display the user list with their specific user role or roles if the user given multiple roles.

thanks guys for answering! cheers!

Comment: can you click to the application frame and provide another screenshot?

Comment: Can you please show you user model and user/index.blade.php

Comment: hi @mukeshkumar I just updated my question. sorry charitra I don't know what you mean. what screen you want to see?

Comment: you need to create  roles relation method  in your model like profile  then you can use this  $users = User::with('roles')->where('name', 'admin')->get(); .

Comment: hi @mukeshkumar I added  public function roles() { return $this->belongsToMany('App\Role'); } in my user model. it gives me "Property [roles] does not exist on this collection instance." but I do DD($users); But why I can see see the role in the relation?

Comment: @Lito can please explain Is that possible one  user has multiple role or single role?

Comment: I mean can you please show me your user and role table migration.

Comment: hI @mukeshkumar i just edit my question. I added the user and roles migration table

Comment: Hello @Lito you can't make relation directly without any foreign key

Comment: You can create relation  with role_user table and then role table.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are calling `$user->role()` instead of `$user->roles()`

to get them as an array to loop through you need to do

```
foreach($user->roles as $role){
  // do something with role here
}
```

Comment: hi @simon this gives me "Property [roles] does not exist on this collection instance"

Comment: its because you have a collection of users you will need to modify your index.blade.php to do foreach($users as $user) {foreach($user->roles as $role){
  // do something with role here
}}

or find the user by id or call User::with('roles')->where('name', 'admin')->first() // not the best approach but that will work

Answer (score 0):

By the looks of it, I think you're wrongly referencing the realation inside your `dashboard.users.index` view: If you're having:

```
$user->role()
```

Change it to:

```
$user->roles()
```

Or simply change your relation name in model. If the relation type is `hasOne`, rename it to `user()` since it will always have one role, no need for plural.

Answer (score 0):

Getting Error in Laravel8 One to Many  get Data between User and Comment

> UserController.php      **BEFORE**

```
 $comment = User::find($id)->comments;  
 return $comment;
```

> UserController.php      **AFTER**

```
$comment = User::find($id)->comment;  
 return $comment;
```